# Trigger Para actualizar Campo cada 24 horas

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Actualice mi pregunta para referenciarme y explicarme mejor a lo que quiero hacer.

En mi tabla tengo un campo llamado dias, quiero que cada 24 horas se ejecute e trigger y reste a ese campo en 1 si tiene un 30 se reste a 29 y asi sucesivamente, pero no se como hacerlo, se que es con un while pero no se como realizarlo en mysql

While dias >= 0 Do
 no se como agregarle el siguiente codigo al trigger con un update para el campo dias

```
floor(((date + (86400 * 30)) - unix_timestamp()) / 86400) as expire_days
```

Comment: pon lo que tengas de código

Comment: @armen no tengo nada de codigo pero buscando en google me encontre con una pagina que me ayudo a saber que es lo que quiero y mas omenos como realizarlo solo me falta saber como generar el while dentro de un trigger en un momento edito mi preugnta

Comment: @armen i update my question